# SQLite (SQLiteStudio 3.3.3): select from hardcoded list of values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I need to select few constants as if it was a table. I found similar question for postgress:

[Select hardcoded values without table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948614/select-hardcoded-values-without-table)

But it doesnt work with SQLite. This:

```
select * from (
  values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
);
```

returns `1` 5 times instead.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: It works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b04a1d982fd76ef7c4869e1532c35f8d

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a bug. According to this it worked in previous version of sqlite: [How do I name the output column in a sqlite values clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913457/how-do-i-name-the-output-column-in-a-sqlite-values-clause)

However this works as expected:

```
with cte(a) as (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))
  select * from cte;
```

Comment: There is no bug: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b04a1d982fd76ef7c4869e1532c35f8d

Comment: It does not work on windows on my machine

Comment: It works fine in any version of SQLite I tried it from 3.15.1 to 3.36.0. Can you reproduce it in a fidde?

Comment: perhaps its SQLiteStudio issue. it is still actual 8 months on